# Google Translate API Response on Browser and Android App\Postman - Arabic Chracters

Tags: android, browser, unicode, character-encoding, google-translate

I'm using following API url of Google.

```
Browser URL Example
> URL Example 1 (URL.encoded): http://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl=ar-AE&tl=en-US&dt=t&q=%D9%85%D8%B1%D8%AD%D8%A8%D8%A7

> URL Example 2: http://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl=ar-AE&tl=en-US&dt=t&q=مرحبا

> Android okhttp Example: "http://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&" +
                "sl=" + sourceLanguage +
                "&tl=" + targetLanguage + "&dt=t&" +
                "q=" + URLEncoder.encode(text, "UTF-8");
```

Converting Arabic to English, if i am executing the following url on chrome browser it is giving me the correct results. But When I execute the following url using okHttp, I'm getting wrong response.

> Response (Chrome) Correct Results: [[["Hi","مرحبا",null,null,1]],null,"ar"]
>
> Response okhttp (android) Wrong Results: [[["I ... ط ± طط¨ط§","ظ…ط±ط­ط¨ط§",null,null,3]],null,"ar"]

OkHttp Code

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

            Log.e("Translate TEXT", URL);

            Call call = client.newCall(new Request.Builder().addHeader("Content-Type","application/json; charset=UTF-8").url(URL).get().build());
            Response response = call.execute();
            if (response.code() == 200 || response.code() == 201) {
                String resp = response.body().string();
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(resp);
                translatedText = jsonArray.getJSONArray(0).getJSONArray(0).getString(0);
                Log.e("RESPONSE 1", translatedText );
}
```

I have tried URLEncoder, UriEncoder and some other solutions available on StackOverFlow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
URL = "http://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&" +
               "sl=" + sourceLanguage +
               "&tl=" + targetLanguage + "&dt=t&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&" +
               "q=" + URLEncoder.encode(text, "UTF-8");
```

I resolved the issue by adding 2 parameters that are "ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8". 
Thanks to following answer link 
https://forum.golangbridge.org/t/google-translate-api-issue-solved/5059/2